# Skipping empty sheets in an excel workbook using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looping through a list of sheets in a workbook and doing some calcs on each sheet. The script was returning an error due to some empty sheets in the workbook. To overcome this problem, I used try..except command. The script runs without any error now but it doesn't return any results.

It is important to mention that the first sheet and some other sheets in the workbook are empty.

```
for sheet in sheet_names:
        try:
            traffic_data=pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name=sheet)                      
            traffic_data2=traffic_data[traffic_data["Time"]=="00-24"]
            24avrg=traffic_data2/24
                
        except:
            pass
```

Is there a way to skip all empty sheets (or return value 0 for them) and consider only sheets that have data in it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can be helpful for your question. You can strip the empty line like following:

```
with open(filename) as f_in:
    lines = filter(None, (line.rstrip() for line in f_in))
```

OR

You can try directly strip data after you read it, in your function

```
data = [l for l in (line.strip() for line in f) if l]
```